# Powershell script to Compare 2 folders and copy same items in other folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to powershell upon studying some tutorials i have built some code for my requirement. But the output was not as expected.please help me.

Requirement:

I have 2 folders A and B.

In folder A new files are present with some changes in directories & Sub- directories.

In Folder B some old/existing files with directories & Sub- directories.

I need to compare the files having same names in folder A and Folder B including directories & Sub- directories completely and then copy files from which are same in both the folders  to folder C with proper directory structure from Folder B.

we can neglect if new files which are present in folder A but not in folder B.

Code I have used:

```
$folderA= \\share\newfiles

$folderB= D:\apps\Existingfiles

$folderC = \\share2\backup

$source1 = (Get-ChildItem -path $folderA)

$dest1 = (Get-ChildItem -path $folderB)

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dest1  -DifferenceObject $source1 -Property Name,Length -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual|Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item "$dest\$($_.Name)" -Destination $backup -Recurse -force
    }
```

Comment: You are just comparing the Name without the subtree part and also trying to copy without the subtree part where such file doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please guide me in correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your `$source1/$dest1` comparable you need to strip the prefixes `$folderA/$folderB` from the FullName and store as a new (calculated) property.

This new property will hold the sub tree part and the name (--> $SubName).

For better understandng I chose other variable names.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\29\SU_1370677.ps1

$RefBase  = 'K:\Bat\'   #  'D:\apps\Existingfiles\'
$DiffBase = 'C:\Bat\'   #  '\\share\newfiles\'
$Target   = 'A:\Bat\'   #  '\\share2\backup\'

$RefTree = Get-ChildItem $RefBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($RefBase,'')}}

$DiffTree =  Get-ChildItem $DiffBase -File -Recurse | Select-Object Length,
           @{n='SubName';e={$_.FullName.Replace($DiffBase,'')}}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $RefTree `
               -DifferenceObject $DiffTree `
               -Property SubName,Length `
               -ExcludeDifferent `
               -IncludeEqual | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq "==" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $SourceFile = Join-Path  $DiffBase $_.SubName
        $TargetFile = Join-Path  $Target   $_.SubName
        $TargetDir  = Split-Path $TargetFile -Parent
        If (!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){MD $TargetDir | Out-Null}
        Copy-Item $SourceFile -Destination $TargetFile -Force
    }
```

BTW `-ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq "=="` is redundant, choose either one.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate working as expected.. Thanks again for guiding me